# paginate download method to pick item from the server in batches

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a method that picks data from the server. How can I paginate it to pick data in batches of 10 in the listview. Snippet of the method is shown

```
private String downloadData()
    {
        HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
        if(con==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            String line;
            StringBuffer jsonData=new StringBuffer();

            System.out.println("json data 123 " + jsonData.capacity() );
            br.close();
            is.close();
            return jsonData.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not that specific I want to give you the logic about how its done.

1) The first thing is if you have pagination view then in the Response you want the Api 
   Developer to send you a link which gives the next page url.

2) After that if you want to load more data, you again do an api call and append those data 
   in list.
3) After that you notify the adapter that the data has changed.

Comment: no its okay. But if you understand the above logic I mentioned then you will be able to do it.